# Ubuntu Studio running slow after some months

Tags: boot, android-studio, top, htop

I am a Ubuntu Studio user and general Linux novice. I installed the latest Ubuntu Studio  on my Dell Vostro 400 Q6600 quad-core, and it ran perfectly for many months. Now it's unusable. When I boot up, even opening the file manager takes a few minutes. Opening a program takes forever. It seems to get a little quicker when left on for some time, but it's essentially unusable.

Of course I've checked all the answers here, but nothing has worked for me. Running `top` shows a list of processes that jumps around so quickly I can't even read it, and I have no idea what I should even be looking for. The only programs I added were Geany and Google Chrome, which I since removed, but the problem persists.

What is a bulletproof way to trace the problem and fix it? Will it be easier to just reinstall it? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is some terminal output requested by Raffa:

free -m:

```
fw@fw-Vostro-400:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3940         412        2974           2         553        3303
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

df -h:

```
fw@fw-Vostro-400:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M  1.4M  393M   1% /run
/dev/sdc1       219G   63G  145G  31% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           395M   20K  395M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Also, df -m:

```
fw@fw-Vostro-400:~$ df -m
Filesystem     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                1947     0      1947   0% /dev
tmpfs                395     2       393   1% /run
/dev/sdc1         223358 64034    147910  31% /
tmpfs               1971     0      1971   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5     1         5   1% /run/lock
tmpfs               1971     0      1971   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                395     1       395   1% /run/user/1000
```

More terminal out from dstat:

```
fw@fw-Vostro-400:~$ dstat 3 50
You did not select any stats, using -cdngy by default.
--total-cpu-usage-- -dsk/total- -net/total- ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai stl| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw 
  2   0  71  26   0| 236k   69k|   0     0 |   0     0 | 231   568 
  0   0  96   4   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 119   302 
  0   0  90  10   0|   0    12k|   0     0 |   0     0 | 116   302 
  0   0  95   5   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 101   234 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 117   297 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  97   233 
  0   0  95   5   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 121   311 
  0   0  98   2   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 103   241 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 110   273 
  0   0  95   5   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 127   319 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  95   231 
  0   0  94   6   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 118   305 
  0   0  98   2   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  96   233 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 116   292 
  0   0  88  12   0|   0  9557B|   0     0 |   0     0 | 101   253 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 124   313 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 113   276 
  0   0  94   6   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 118   299 
  0   0  98   2   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 101   245 
  0   0  95   5   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 114   292 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  96   232 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 121   315 
  0   0  94   5   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 100   246 
--total-cpu-usage-- -dsk/total- -net/total- ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai stl| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw 
  0   0  96   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 112   280 
  0   0  97   2   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 120   292 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  96   238 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 110   280 
  0   0  95   5   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 102   243 
  0   0  96   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 119   300 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 105   257 
  0   0  95   4   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 115   291 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 115   276 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 116   299 
  0   0  95   5   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 100   241 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 112   291 
  0   0  95   4   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 102   244 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 106   276 
  0   0  98   2   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 106   259 
  0   0  95   5   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 104   254 
  0   0  96   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 118   301 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  96   234 
  0   0  95   5   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 121   325 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  98   242 
  0   0  96   4   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 117   296 
  0   0  96   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  97   243 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 116   294 
--total-cpu-usage-- -dsk/total- -net/total- ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai stl| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw 
  0   0  94   6   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 102   248 
  0   0  97   3   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 117   305 
  0   0  97   2   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  99   244 
  0   0  95   5   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 120   314 



fw@fw-Vostro-400:~$ dstat --top-cpu --top-cputime --top-cputime-avg --top-io --proc-count --thermal 3 50
Module dstat_thermal failed to load. (Needs kernel ACPI or IBM-ACPI support)
Terminal width too small, trimming output.
-most-expensive- --highest-total-- -highest-average- ----most-expensive---->
  cpu process   | cputime process | cputime process |     i/o process      >
Xorg         0.0|Xorg          693|kerneloops    229|bash         36k   21k>
Xorg         0.3|Xorg         3194|xfce4-termina 126|xfce4-termi 314B 9141B>
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         1959|Xorg         93.3|xfce4-termi 203B 4845B>
ksoftirqd/1  0.2|xfce4-termina1750|kerneloops    395|xfce4-termi 203B 4959B>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         2051|irqbalance    122|xfce4-termi 201B 4996B>
                |Xorg         1966|Xorg         81.9|xfce4-termi 198B 4821B>
Xorg         0.3|Xorg         1909|Xorg         95.5|xfce4-termi 201B 4840B>
xfce4-termina0.3|Xorg         2166|Xorg          103|xfce4-termi 203B 4899B>
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         2061|irqbalance    122|xfce4-termi 201B 5029B>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         2003|Xorg          100|xfce4-termi 203B 4972B>
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         2125|Xorg          106|xfce4-termi 201B 4963B>
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         2068|irqbalance    127|xfce4-termi 203B 4991B>
colord-sane  3.8|colord-sane    76|colord-sane   231|xfce4-termi 203B 5212B>
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         2393|Xorg          109|xfce4-termi 203B 5121B>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         1755|xfce4-termina92.1|xfce4-termi 203B 5104B>
xfwm4        0.2|Xorg         2135|Xorg          102|xfce4-termi 203B 5185B>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         2218|systemd       495|xfce4-termi 203B 5287B>
Xorg         0.3|Xorg         2209|Xorg          105|xfce4-termi 203B 5220B>
                |Xorg         2194|irqbalance    128|xfce4-termi 198B 5307B>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         2374|Xorg          113|xfce4-termi 198B 5464B>
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         2528|kerneloops    397|xfce4-termi 203B 5632B>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         2453|irqbalance    122|xfce4-termi 201B 5792B>
                |Xorg         2365|Xorg          113|xfce4-termi 198B 5913B>
-most-expensive- --highest-total-- -highest-average- ----most-expensive---->
  cpu process   | cputime process | cputime process |     i/o process      >
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         3698|kerneloops    448|xfce4-termi 315B   10k>
Xorg         0.3|xfce4-termina2413|xfce4-termina 142|xfce4-termi 203B 5865B>
xfce4-termina0.2|xfce4-termina2392|xfce4-termina 133|xfce4-termi 201B 5732B>
xfce4-termina0.2|xfce4-termina2532|xfce4-termina 158|xfce4-termi 201B 5675B>
Xorg         0.2|xfce4-termina2486|xfce4-termina 146|xfce4-termi 201B 5697B>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         2543|xfce4-termina 125|xfce4-termi 201B 5704B>
xfce4-termina0.2|xfce4-termina2384|xfce4-termina 140|xfce4-termi 201B 5747B>
                |Xorg         1812|Xorg         90.6|xfce4-termi 198B 5692B>
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         2247|irqbalance    126|xfce4-termi 198B 5667B>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         2350|Xorg          112|xfce4-termi 201B 5807B>
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         2529|Xorg          115|xfce4-termi 201B 5805B>
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         1885|irqbalance    120|xfce4-termi 201B 5789B>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         2382|Xorg          113|xfce4-termi 203B 5863B>
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         2330|Xorg          111|xfce4-termi 201B 5783B>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         2362|Xorg          112|xfce4-termi 201B 5788B>
irq/23-ehci_h0.2|Xorg         2435|irqbalance    121|xfce4-termi 198B 5763B>
xfwm4        0.2|Xorg         2306|Xorg          110|xfce4-termi 201B 5783B>
Xorg         0.3|Xorg         2481|kerneloops    397|xfce4-termi 201B 5816B>
kworker/1:1H-0.2|Xorg         2340|irqbalance    110|xfce4-termi 198B 5783B>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         2395|Xorg          114|xfce4-termi 201B 5916B>
                |Xorg         2007|kerneloops    397|xfce4-termi 198B 5757B>
Xorg         0.3|Xorg         2357|Xorg          112|xfce4-termi 198B 5757B>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         1931|Xorg         91.9|xfce4-termi 201B 5980B>
-most-expensive- --highest-total-- -highest-average- ----most-expensive---->
  cpu process   | cputime process | cputime process |     i/o process      >
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         3521|xfce4-termina98.7|xfce4-termi 317B   11k>
xfce4-termina0.2|Xorg         2474|Xorg          108|xfce4-termi 201B 5845B>
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         2471|irqbalance    125|xfce4-termi 203B 5853B>
Xorg         0.2|Xorg         2348|Xorg          107|xfce4-termi 201B 5769B>
```

Latest terminal output suggested by Raffa:

```
fw@fw-Vostro-400:~$ tail -50 /var/log/kern.log
Mar 31 23:20:27 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [   86.454459] audit: type=1400 audit(1585689627.893:37): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/tmp/tumbler-X611TI0.png" pid=1595 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="wc" denied_mask="wc" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Mar 31 23:20:58 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  116.923649] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Mar 31 23:20:58 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  117.052736] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=2e04, idProduct=c025, bcdDevice= 3.18
Mar 31 23:20:58 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  117.052739] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 31 23:20:58 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  117.052741] usb 2-4: Product: Android
Mar 31 23:20:58 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  117.052743] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Android
Mar 31 23:20:58 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  117.052745] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: PLEGAR1790822473
Mar 31 23:20:58 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  117.054494] usb-storage 2-4:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar 31 23:20:58 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  117.055788] scsi host5: usb-storage 2-4:1.1
Mar 31 23:20:59 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  118.093384] scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM            Linux    File-CD Gadget   0318 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Mar 31 23:20:59 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  118.094362] sr 5:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
Mar 31 23:20:59 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  118.095991] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
Mar 31 23:20:59 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  118.096688] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
Mar 31 23:20:59 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  118.096787] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg8 type 5
Mar 31 23:21:07 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  126.071531] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
Mar 31 23:21:07 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  126.339691] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Mar 31 23:21:07 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  126.468616] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=2e04, idProduct=c022, bcdDevice= 3.18
Mar 31 23:21:07 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  126.468619] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 31 23:21:07 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  126.468621] usb 2-4: Product: Android
Mar 31 23:21:07 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  126.468623] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Android
Mar 31 23:21:07 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  126.468625] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: PLEGAR1790822473
Mar 31 23:21:11 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  130.414777] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
Mar 31 23:21:15 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  133.640251] rndis_host 2-4:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1d.7-4, RNDIS device, da:df:e8:49:c7:bc
Mar 31 23:21:15 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  133.640285] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
Mar 31 23:21:15 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  133.667478] rndis_host 2-4:1.0 enp0s29f7u4: renamed from usb0
Mar 31 23:21:32 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  150.644620] perf: interrupt took too long (2510 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79000
Mar 31 22:27:37 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [  515.261379] perf: interrupt took too long (3156 > 3137), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63000
Mar 31 22:55:19 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2176.641248] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Mar 31 22:55:19 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2176.780468] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=5678, bcdDevice= 2.00
Mar 31 22:55:19 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2176.780471] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 31 22:55:19 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2176.780473] usb 2-3: Product: Disk 2.0
Mar 31 22:55:19 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2176.780475] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: USB
Mar 31 22:55:19 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2176.780476] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 92070804D5158059117
Mar 31 22:55:19 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2176.780872] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mar 31 22:55:19 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2176.783351] scsi host5: usb-storage 2-3:1.0
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.793613] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     VendorCo ProductCode      2.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.793984] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg8 type 0
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.797824] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdh] 7864320 512-byte logical blocks: (4.03 GB/3.75 GiB)
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.798475] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdh] Write Protect is off
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.798478] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdh] Mode Sense: 33 00 00 00
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.799098] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page found
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.799103] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.803864]  sdh: sdh1
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.806470] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI removable disk
Mar 31 22:55:26 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2183.780099] FAT-fs (sdh1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2208.543640] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 5
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2208.545123] rndis_host 2-4:1.0 enp0s29f7u4: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:1d.7-4, RNDIS device
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2210.115400] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 6
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2210.115996] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 2049 flags 1
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2210.116001] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 1, lost async page write


fw@fw-Vostro-400:~$ ls -l /var/crash/
total 0


fw@fw-Vostro-400:~$ tail -50 /var/log/syslog
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.798478] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdh] Mode Sense: 33 00 00 00
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.799098] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdh] No Caching mode page found
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.799103] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.803864]  sdh: sdh1
Mar 31 22:55:20 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2177.806470] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI removable disk
Mar 31 22:55:26 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2183.780099] FAT-fs (sdh1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
Mar 31 22:55:27 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1]: Created slice system-clean\x2dmount\x2dpoint.slice.
Mar 31 22:55:27 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1]: Started Clean the /media/fw/UBUNTU-STUD mount point.
Mar 31 22:55:27 fw-Vostro-400 udisksd[599]: Mounted /dev/sdh1 at /media/fw/UBUNTU-STUD on behalf of uid 1000
Mar 31 22:55:32 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2208.543640] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 5
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2208.545123] rndis_host 2-4:1.0 enp0s29f7u4: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:1d.7-4, RNDIS device
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 dhclient[1694]: receive_packet failed on enp0s29f7u4: Network is down
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 avahi-daemon[602]: Interface enp0s29f7u4.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 avahi-daemon[602]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s29f7u4.IPv6 with address fe80::4017:82c0:893:3ed8.
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 avahi-daemon[602]: Interface enp0s29f7u4.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 avahi-daemon[602]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s29f7u4.IPv4 with address 192.168.42.215.
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 avahi-daemon[602]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::4017:82c0:893:3ed8 on enp0s29f7u4.
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 avahi-daemon[602]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.42.215 on enp0s29f7u4.
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1585688151.0440] device (enp0s29f7u4): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 whoopsie[1425]: [22:55:51] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 whoopsie[1425]: [22:55:51] offline
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 whoopsie[1425]: [22:55:51] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1585688151.0509] dhcp4 (enp0s29f7u4): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1694
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1585688151.0510] dhcp4 (enp0s29f7u4): state changed bound -> done
Mar 31 22:55:51 fw-Vostro-400 NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1585688151.0598] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 dbus-daemon[598]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=613 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 dbus-daemon[598]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [enp0s29f7u4]: new request (1 scripts)
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [enp0s29f7u4]: start running ordered scripts...
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2210.115400] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 6
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2210.115996] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 2049 flags 1
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 kernel: [ 2210.116001] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 1, lost async page write
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 udisksd[599]: Cleaning up mount point /media/fw/UBUNTU-STUD (device 8:113 no longer exists)
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1096]: media-fw-UBUNTU\x2dSTUD.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1]: media-fw-UBUNTU\x2dSTUD.mount: Succeeded.
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1]: Stopping Clean the /media/fw/UBUNTU-STUD mount point...
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1]: clean-mount-point@media-fw-UBUNTU\x2dSTUD.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 22:55:52 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1]: Stopped Clean the /media/fw/UBUNTU-STUD mount point.
Mar 31 22:55:53 fw-Vostro-400 NetworkManager[613]: <warn>  [1585688153.6217] dns-sd-resolved[0x557b119a4820]: Failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchLink: Link 3 not known
Mar 31 22:55:53 fw-Vostro-400 NetworkManager[613]: <warn>  [1585688153.6218] dns-sd-resolved[0x557b119a4820]: Failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchLink: Link 3 not known
Mar 31 22:55:53 fw-Vostro-400 NetworkManager[613]: message repeated 2 times: [ <warn>  [1585688153.6218] dns-sd-resolved[0x557b119a4820]: Failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchLink: Link 3 not known]
Mar 31 22:55:53 fw-Vostro-400 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Mar 31 22:56:03 fw-Vostro-400 PackageKit: daemon quit
Mar 31 22:56:03 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Mar 31 22:56:03 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
Mar 31 22:56:04 fw-Vostro-400 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.


fw@fw-Vostro-400:~$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):              2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               23
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8300  @ 2.83GHz
Stepping:            6
CPU MHz:             2046.626
CPU max MHz:         2831.0000
CPU min MHz:         1998.0000
BogoMIPS:            5652.04
Virtualisation:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0,1
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm
fw@fw-Vostro-400:~$ tail -50 /var/log/Xorg*.log
tail: option used in invalid context -- 5


fw@fw-Vostro-400:~$ sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-5.0.0-32-lowlatency] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     KINGSTON SA400S37240G
Serial Number:    50026B76827DDD50
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0026b7 6827ddd50
Firmware Version: SBFKB1D2
User Capacity:    240,057,409,536 bytes [240 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Mar 31 23:02:52 2020 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (65535) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  30) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   000   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1916
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       830
148 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
149 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       16
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   010    Old_age   Offline      -       11
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       655375
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       382
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   076   063   000    Old_age   Always       -       24 (Min/Max 14/37)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
218 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
231 Temperature_Celsius     0x0000   001   001   000    Old_age   Offline      -       99
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1069
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       716
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1064
244 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       10
245 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       15
246 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       78896

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Here's a Pastebin for `tail -n 50 /var/log/Xorg*.log`: https://pastebin.com/QBTrzXEg

```
fw@fw-Vostro-400:~$ lspci | grep ' VGA '
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV630 XT [Radeon HD 2600 XT]
```

Comment: You started the road to bulletproof troubleshooting already: What you should be looking for when using `top` during a minute or two is a *pattern*: Is your CPU maxed out? Or your memory? And which processes seem to be using the most of those resources? Also look at `free` to see if you swapping (which often makes the system seem sluggish).

Comment: Maybe try Task Manager instead of top which allows to sort my CPU load and memory. Also check if your root partition is full.

Comment: Task Manager shows at the top of the list with 2% CPU. There are 182 processes. CPU between 2 and 4%, memory 15%. Seems normal  What now?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `free -m`

Comment: Please also add the output of `df -h`

Comment: @Raffa done. Please check the question again?

Comment: So far is normal. Please install `dstat` by running `sudo apt install dstat` then run these two commands and see if something is out of the norm or if you prefer add the output to your question for us to inspect. the first command `dstat 3 50` and the second command `dstat --top-cpu --top-cputime --top-cputime-avg --top-io --proc-count --thermal 3 50`

Comment: Thanks Raffa. Edited question with suggested output

Comment: Output shows possible kernel crashes and long Xorg CPU usage times. Let's check logs for kernel crashes `tail -50 /var/log/kern.log` and application crashes `ls -l /var/crash/` and system log `tail -50 /var/log/syslog` and CPU parameters `lscpu` and Xorg log `tail -50 /var/log/Xorg*.log`. Let's also check for drive SMART errors if any `sudo smartctl --quietmode=errorsonly --all /dev/sdc`. You might need to install `sudo apt install smartmontools` for the SMART check if not already installed. Please add the output of those to your question.

Comment: Have you made changes to color profiles or Xorg display setting?

Comment: No I didn't make any profile changers (that I'm aware of). I've added the new terminal output you suggested.

Comment: Xorg logs are missing. Your version of `tail` doesn't like wildcard `*` . Please try again with `tail -n 50 /var/log/Xorg*.log` and see if it works now. If not please do `ls /var/log/X*` and see how many Xorg log files are there. The output will be something like `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and maybe `/var/log/Xorg.1.log` and more. do `cat ` or `tail -50` on all of them and add the output.

Comment: Question exceeding character limit. Here's a Pastebin for `tail -n 50 /var/log/Xorg*.log`: https://pastebin.com/QBTrzXEg Will add this to question as well.

Comment: There are some issues in your Xorg log (crashes) . Please disconnect all USB and external devices ie (headphones, speakers, cameras, additional monitors ....) and change your keyboard and mouse if you have extra ones or connect them to different USB ports if you don't. Then reboot your computer and see how it goes. Also add the output of `tail -n 400 /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "status installed"` to inspect the lately updated and installed packages.

Comment: Ok some progress... I removed a USB software license dongle that was being used in a Windows program on same PC and moved the USB keyboard to another port. The screen refresh is not jaggy now, however it is still very slow overall. It takes about ten minutes to load Libre office or Firefox. So it's better but still very slow..

Comment: There was no output for tail -n 400 /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "status installed"

Comment: It is now narrowing to be Xorg related. Let's inspect your video hardware. Please add the output of `sudo lshw -C display` and `lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs -i lspci -v -s {}`

Comment: Also please add the output of `apt policy xserver-xorg-input-*`

Comment: Thanks Raffa. Can you check this command please? `lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs -i lspci -v -s {}` Is this a single command, or two?. I ran it and got lspci usage instructions. Thanks

Comment: It's one command but a bit complex to get extra info. If it does not work on your system running just `lspci | grep ' VGA '` will work

Comment: Added latest output to question.

Comment: Thank you but you missed `sudo lshw -C display` an `apt policy xserver-xorg-input-*` .We need the output of these tow commands. The first will give more details about your video hardware and the second will show Xorg's input related packages status.

Comment: Thanks. Here's a new Pastebin with those commands. https://pastebin.com/wk0y5FqE The computer is running faster now, thanks to removing the USB dongle. Let me know if you see something else off? Thanks again

Comment: pastebin output looks good. Packages are current for your version of Ubuntu. Is the computer speed back to normal or not yet? as a VGA driver can be reinstalled if needed and that might help as well.

Comment: It's intermittent. Worked fine yesterday for a while. Now back to slow today. Takes minutes to respond to anything. Mouse rollover takes a few seconds to highlight an icon. Could the problem be the VGA driver? Why would it be intermittent in that case?

Comment: Your Xorg log contains resolution related issues. This is usually caused by driver or Xorg.config miss-configuration.  To rule that out you could try removing ATI drivers `sudo apt purge "fglrx.*"` then back up xorg.conf to a different name `sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old` then reinstall Xorg `sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64` then reconfigure Xorg `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` then properly install drivers `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` then reboot and report back

Comment: Thanks. To 'reconfigure Xorg' I just have to run that command, right? Or is there something I need to set there? (Just in case I start and get stuck) ;)

Comment: That's right. Just run the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

Comment: "fglrx.*" didn't match anything and there's no xorg.conf file. What should I do?

Comment: No problem. continue

Comment: After a long time: `No drivers found for installation.` :/

Comment: Xorg reinstall went well? reboot and report back if it is better or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106354/discussion-between-freeworlder-and-raffa).